# Subquery for count of equal bridges and highways for each state

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables, a table with states names, the highways in the state, and the bridges in the state.  I want to make a query that tell me the number of states where the number of highways and bridges are equal.  I currently have this query, the subquery gets the number of highways in each state and number of bridges and counts them.  I need to take the next step to get the total number of states where they are equivlant. My outer count just get a total number not, and doesn't check if the number of briges and highways are equilant. If add a where cause to the main statement, I get an error "can't group by". But I Not sure how in the subquery to check if the counts are the same either.  Guidaunace on how to change the query would be helpful.

```
SELECT count(*)
from
    (SELECT count(h.name), count(b.name)
    FROM state c
    INNER JOIN highways h
    on c.code = l.code
    INNER JOIN bridge b
    on c.code = g.code
    Group By c.code
    );
```

"state"
Code is our key that is unquie for each state

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Ohio | OH |
| Wisconsin | WI |

"highways"

two state codes to refer to border between two states

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| OH | 76 |
| OH | 81 |
| OH | 25 |
| WI | 76 |
| WI | 78 |

"bridges"
(sorry for not unquie names)

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| OH | bridge1 |
| OH | bridge2 |
| WI | bridge3 |
| WI | bridge4 |

Comment: After GROUP BY add HAVING count(h.name) = count(b.name)

Comment: thank u,  that so simple an did the trick

Comment: That did the trick??? That will return all states, as `count(h.name)` = `count(b.name)` = `count(*)`.

Comment: You should be able to group by `c.code`. But you confused aliases. Sometimes its `h` and `b`, sometimes its `l` and `g`. The query won't give you the desired counts, though, because you are cross joining each state's bridges and highways. If a state has ten bridges and five highways, you produce fifty rows (10 x 5 = 50) which you then count. As neither `h.name` nor `b.name` will be null, you get the same amount as with a mere `count(*)`. Don't cross join bridges and highways. Count bridges, count highways, then join the counts to their state.

Comment: And don't inner join, but outer join the counts. A state with zero bridges and zero highways has the same amount of bridges and highways, too. (Otherwise you wouldn't need the state table at all here and could just inner join the count queries on state code and count.)

Answer (score 1):

You only need the 2nd and 3rd tables. It's also a good habit to count first and just then connect the tables.

```
with h as 
(
select   code
        ,count(*) as h_cnt
from     highways
group by code
),

b as 
(
select   code
        ,count(*) as b_cnt
from     bridges
group by code
)

select count(*) as s_cnt
from   h join b using(code) where h_cnt = b_cnt
```

| S_CNT |
| --- |
| 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nM-6q6z0)

Comment: Don't post code-only answers. Tell the OP what's wrong with their query and how your query overcomes those issues.